# error: no matching function for call to set(boost::beast::http::field, std::string_view&)’

Tags: boost, boost-beast

```
boost_1_82_0/boost/beast/core/string_type.hpp:18:1: note: ‘#pragma message: BOOST_BEAST_USE_STD_STRING_VIEW is deprecated, use BOOST_NO_CXX17_HDR_STRING_VIEW instead’
   18 | BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE("BOOST_BEAST_USE_STD_STRING_VIEW is deprecated, use BOOST_NO_CXX17_HDR_STRING_VIEW instead");

Legacy code:
#define BOOST_BEAST_USE_STD_STRING_VIEW

std::string_view my_host;
beast::http::request<http::empty_body> my_request;
my_request.set(http::field::host, my_host);

Updated code: changes made for boost v1.82
#define BOOST_NO_CXX17_HDR_STRING_VIEW
```

Now I see the following errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::beast::http::message<true, boost::beast::http::empty_body, boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::allocator<char> >
>::set(boost::beast::http::field, std::string_view&)’
```

**Question**> What is the best way to adapt the legacy code and migrate it to the v1.82?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch for string_view types is deprecated, as you already know.

The good news is, it is no longer needed. By dropping the deprecated define (`BOOST_BEAST_USE_STD_STRING_VIEW`) everything should compile.

The reason is that Beast changed to Boost Core's `string_view` implementation. This one is interoperable with all common string-view implementations (Boost Utility, Boost Core, `boost::string_ref`, `std::string_view`).

Source: I [implemented the PR](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/2363) for this change before Boost 1.81